# Can you change the behavior of double.parse?

Tags: c#

I have used double.parse a lot in my project and now found issues that other users get problems.

I should have used:

```
double.parse(string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

everywhere.

Can I change the behavior of `double.parse` or do I really need to go to all places in the code and do this manually?

Comment: What do you mean by override? Do you have a class that is a subclass of `double` where you are writing overriding methods?

Comment: `double` is a struct, so you can inherit anyway. I think what you want is not to inherit, you simply need to refactor `double.Parse` everywhere in your code. You can use tools such as ReSharper to help you with that.

Comment: Overriding global state means that all components that you don't control, such as the BCL or libraries, might malfunction.

Comment: "Overriding" is the wrong term here. He means "Call `double.parse(string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` when `double.parse(string)` appears in the code"

Comment: exactly Joe! sorry I m still a beginner

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot override a static method.

You will have to manually refactor your code to use the correct overload of `double.Parse`.

Comment: Or probably introduce some utils function to call proper overload of double.Parse. Easier to change in future.

Answer (score 3):

There's a possibility to override the whole application's culture by using

```
Application.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

in the application's main method.

So all `double.Parse(string)` are now equal to `double.Parse(string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, because it uses the [invariant culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) internally.

But be aware that it changes *EVERYTHING* that uses formating.
That means, `double.ToString()` also uses the invariant culture.
If this is a problem, then you have to replace every occurance of `double.Parse(string)`
by `double.Parse(string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`!